# Calc with bison and flex doesn't work operation negative

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I have a problem with this Bison program. I don't know why Reuse does not work. For the operation with the negative numbers, I just use the same line for the get the first number and to operate with more operations. I just changed the first number to negative.

**`calc.y`**

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int yylex();
extern int yyparse();
extern FILE* yyin;

void yyerror(const char* s);
%}

%union {
    int ival;
    float fval;
}

%token<ival> T_INT
%token<fval> T_FLOAT
%token T_PLUS T_MINUS T_MULTIPLY T_DIVIDE T_LEFT T_RIGHT
%token T_NEWLINE T_QUIT
%left T_PLUS T_MINUS
%left T_MULTIPLY T_DIVIDE

%type<ival> expression
%type<fval> mixed_expression

%start calculation

%%

calculation: 
       | calculation line
;

line: T_NEWLINE
    | mixed_expression T_NEWLINE { printf("\tResult: %f\n", $1);}
    | expression T_NEWLINE { printf("\tResult: %i\n", $1); } 
    | T_QUIT T_NEWLINE { printf("bye!\n"); exit(0); }
;

mixed_expression: T_FLOAT                        { $$ = $1; }
      | T_MINUS T_FLOAT  { $$ = -$2; }    
      | mixed_expression T_PLUS mixed_expression     { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MINUS mixed_expression    { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MULTIPLY mixed_expression { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_DIVIDE mixed_expression   { $$ = $1 / $3; }
      | T_LEFT mixed_expression T_RIGHT      { $$ = $2; }
      | T_MINUS mixed_expression T_RIGHT         { $$ = -$2; }
      | expression T_PLUS mixed_expression       { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | expression T_MINUS mixed_expression      { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | expression T_MULTIPLY mixed_expression   { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | expression T_DIVIDE mixed_expression     { $$ = $1 / $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_PLUS expression       { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MINUS expression      { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MULTIPLY expression   { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_DIVIDE expression     { $$ = $1 / $3; }
      | expression T_DIVIDE expression       { $$ = $1 / (float)$3; }
;

expression: T_INT               { $$ = $1; }

      | expression T_PLUS expression    { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | expression T_MINUS expression   { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | expression T_MULTIPLY expression    { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | T_LEFT expression T_RIGHT       { $$ = $2; }
      | T_MINUS T_INT   { $$ = -$2; }
;

%%

int main() {
    yyin = stdin;

    do { 
        yyparse();
    } while(!feof(yyin));

    return 0;
}

void yyerror(const char* s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Parse error: %s\n", s);
    exit(1);
}
```

**`calclex.l`**

```
%option noyywrap

%{
#include <stdio.h>

#define YY_DECL int yylex()

#include "calc.tab.h"

%}

%%

[ \t]   ; // ignore all whitespace
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+  {yylval.fval = atof(yytext); return T_FLOAT;}
[0-9]+      {yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return T_INT;}
\n      {return T_NEWLINE;}
"+"     {return T_PLUS;}
"-"     {return T_MINUS;}
"*"     {return T_MULTIPLY;}
"/"     {return T_DIVIDE;}
"("     {return T_LEFT;}
")"     {return T_RIGHT;}
"exit"      {return T_QUIT;}
"quit"      {return T_QUIT;}

%%
```

Comment: The reason for that problem is called "unary minus". You could have taken a short glimpse into Bison's fine manual at e.g.: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Infix-Calc.html but, well, who reads the manual ;-)

Comment: uhmmm well i will try, i am new in this environment then i dont know how really works this. but thanks i will try do the best

Comment: Unary minus needs to be right associative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in my comment, the problem is called "unary minus" and it describes the trouble of distinguishing the normal subtraction operation `a - b` from the negation operation `0 - a` if it is abbreviated to `-a`. The common solution is to add a bit of code to make the minus-symbol act as two different operators depending on position. It is done in Bison by implementing a precedence for a non-existing symbol (here `NEG`) and bind that precedence to the case `-a`.

You need to do it twice in your code, once for `T_FLOAT` and the second time for `T_INT`. I also deleted one line that made no sense, at least for me.

`calc.y`:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int yylex();
extern int yyparse();
extern FILE* yyin;

void yyerror(const char* s);
%}

%union {
    int ival;
    float fval;
}

%token<ival> T_INT
%token<fval> T_FLOAT
%token T_PLUS T_MINUS T_MULTIPLY T_DIVIDE T_LEFT T_RIGHT
%token T_NEWLINE T_QUIT
%left T_PLUS T_MINUS
%left T_MULTIPLY T_DIVIDE

%precedence NEG   /* unary minus */

%type<ival> expression
%type<fval> mixed_expression

%start calculation

%%

calculation: 
       | calculation line
;

line: T_NEWLINE
    | mixed_expression T_NEWLINE { printf("\tResult: %f\n", $1);}
    | expression T_NEWLINE       { printf("\tResult: %i\n", $1); } 
    | T_QUIT T_NEWLINE           { printf("bye!\n"); exit(0); }
;

mixed_expression: T_FLOAT                            { $$ = $1; }
      | T_MINUS mixed_expression %prec NEG           { $$ = -$2; }    
      | mixed_expression T_PLUS mixed_expression     { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MINUS mixed_expression    { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MULTIPLY mixed_expression { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_DIVIDE mixed_expression   { $$ = $1 / $3; }
      | T_LEFT mixed_expression T_RIGHT              { $$ = $2; }
      /* | T_MINUS mixed_expression T_RIGHT             { $$ = -$2; } */
      | expression T_PLUS mixed_expression           { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | expression T_MINUS mixed_expression          { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | expression T_MULTIPLY mixed_expression       { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | expression T_DIVIDE mixed_expression         { $$ = $1 / $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_PLUS expression           { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MINUS expression          { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MULTIPLY expression       { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_DIVIDE expression         { $$ = $1 / $3; }
      | expression T_DIVIDE expression               { $$ = $1 / (float)$3; }
;

expression: T_INT                                    { $$ = $1; }
      | expression T_PLUS expression                 { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | expression T_MINUS expression                { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | expression T_MULTIPLY expression             { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | T_LEFT expression T_RIGHT                    { $$ = $2; }
      | T_MINUS expression  %prec NEG                { $$ = -$2; }
;

%%

int main() {
    yyin = stdin;
    do { 
        yyparse();
    } while(!feof(yyin));
    return 0;
}

void yyerror(const char* s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Parse error: %s\n", s);
    exit(1);
}
```

The file `calclex.l` can be left unchanged (although a floating point number is a bit more complicated).

Comment: One might also want to add precedence and associativity to the remaining operators, depending on the language you wish to implement. (Or you could factor out the grammar, but since Bison will do operator precedence for you, why bother? :-) )

Comment: thanks guys  But I did not understand how to apply it and so 
I did it my way and it works
http://prntscr.com/f9nvlh

Comment: @torek according to the goals of SO: one question, one answer. I learned to restrict myself here at SO, otherwise this answer would have exceeded SO's length restriction by a magnitude ;-)